# Create Dictionary with Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe which is called "df" as follows.

[image]

My goal is to create a dictionary. The key is gonna be poiid and values are gonna be lng and lat for dictionary.

Example dictionary output

```
{0: (30.2359091167, -97.7951395833),
 1: (30.2691029532, -97.7493953705),
 2: (30.2557309927, -97.7633857727),
 3: (30.2634181234, -97.7575966669),
 4: (30.2742918584, -97.7405226231),
 5: (30.261599404, -97.7585805953),
...
```

My solution;

```
dictionary = df.groupby('poiid')['lng'].agg(set).to_dict()
```

**my solution works but I couldn't add the 'lat' column into the dictionary.**

I am open to see other solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set your index as `poiid` so that when you want to create a dictionary, key would be `poiid`. Then get the columns you want and make them `tuple`. In the last step, you create a dictionary out of it.

```
df = df.set_index('poiid')[['lng', 'lat']].apply(tuple, axis=1).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set poiid as index with `df = df.set_index("poiid")` then use `df.to_dict("index")`